# libxml2 - xmlTextReaderPreservePattern - centos5 - libxml2-2.9.1 - gcc

Tags: c, xml, gcc, xpath, libxml2

Trying to used "xmlTextReaderPreservePattern".

It does not work when i have namespace qualifiers in the xpath. I get seg faults.

I do have a need for multiple namespaces within the same xml.

Any ideas ?

```
const char *pattern = "/wrapper:TestMessage/wrapper:Header/head:Frame/head:Id/head:StoreId/head:SysId/head:UserId"; // does not give seg fault
//const char *pattern = "/TestMessage/Header/Frame/Id/StoreId/SysId/UserId"; //does give seg fault
const char *namespace = "xmlns='urn:wrapper' xmlns:head='urn:std:header:tech:xsd:headeVersion.001.001.01' xmlns:message='urn:std:message:tech:xsd:messageVersion.001.001.01' "; // ddoes not give seg fault
//const char *pattern = "test"; // does not give seg fault
//const char *namespace = "test"; // does not give seg fault

if (xmlTextReaderPreservePattern(reader, (const xmlChar *) pattern, (const xmlChar **) &namespace) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s : failed add preserve pattern %s\n",   XMLFileName, (const char *) pattern);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
const char *namespace[] = {"urn:wrapper", "wrapper", "urn:std:header:tech:xsd:headeVersion.001.001.01", "head", "urn:std:message:tech:xsd:messageVersion.001.001.01", "message"};
```

What does not work is xpath with functions like text(), for example.

```
onst char *pattern = "/wrapper:TestMessage/wrapper:Header/head:Frame/head:Id/head:StoreId/head:SysId/head:UserId/text()";
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing knowledge like this. The API is rarely documented or used. This is very helpful.

Comment: Use [xmlPatternStreamable](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-pattern.html#xmlPatternMatch) to find out whether a pattern is supported